# Track Page Load Progress in percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress, pageload

Is it possible to show progress of loading page without ajax?

I had come to know about [THIS](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/), That It is possible.

But How can I do it in pure javascript or jquery?

Any Ideas, views?

Right now I'm using

```
var pageLoadStart=true,pageLoaded=false;
window.onload=function(){
pageLoaded=true;
pageLoadStart=false;
}
```

But It cant give you progress in percentage. So is it possible? How?

Comment: http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/progress.htm is this what your looking for?

Comment: Nope, It is waiting only for images to Load, but I need a solution for dynamically generated (ajax) content too, which should also support large js, css files and external element load too. @Stefan Thanks btw.

Comment: You can try adding script tags in your code wich add a small amount to a variable each time. But this will make your code really messy and its not the best solution i think.

Comment: Well Yeah, I thought about it, But How can I add it to externally included `<script>'s` like `FB SDK` and others?

Comment: Just add this script tag under the other one wich loads in your .js file? <script src="...."></script>
<script>var percentage = 20;</script>